# How can I compare and find if two histograms are the same?

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm trying to compare and check if two images match each other. I couldn't find proper tutorials on comparing with OpenCV java in android studio. So, I've found some steps and started calculating the histograms, so that I can compare the histograms of the two images then to see if they matches.

I've coded the below way to calculate the histogram and then compare it.

```
Mat matB2 = new Mat(sourceSize, sourceMat.type());
                Mat matG2 = new Mat(sourceSize, sourceMat.type());
                Mat matR2 = new Mat(sourceSize, sourceMat.type());

                    Imgproc.calcHist(channels2, allChannel2[0], new Mat(),  matB2, hisSize2, histRange2);
                    Imgproc.calcHist(channels2, allChannel2[1], new Mat(), matG2, hisSize2, histRange2);
                    Imgproc.calcHist(channels2, allChannel2[2], new Mat(), matR2, hisSize2, histRange2);

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    int graphHeight2 = 300;
                    int graphWidth2 = 200;
                    int binWidth2 = 3;

                    Mat graphMat2 = new Mat(graphHeight2, graphWidth2, CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(0, 0, 0));

                    //Normalize channel
                    Core.normalize(matB2, matB2, graphMat2.height(), 0, Core.NORM_INF);
                    Core.normalize(matG2, matG2, graphMat2.height(), 0, Core.NORM_INF);
                    Core.normalize(matR2, matR2, graphMat2.height(), 0, Core.NORM_INF);



  //Comparing histograms
                    int compareMethod = 1;
                    double comparisonValueB = Imgproc.compareHist(matB,matB2, Imgproc.CV_COMP_CORREL);
                    double comparisonValueG = Imgproc.compareHist(matG,matG2,Imgproc.CV_COMP_CORREL);
                    double comparisonValueR = Imgproc.compareHist(matR,matR2,Imgproc.CV_COMP_CORREL);

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "comparisonValueB::"+comparisonValueB, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "comparisonValueG::"+comparisonValueG, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "comparisonValueR::"+comparisonValueR, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

However the results I got from the three toasts I've added with the compare values are,

- **comparisonValueB:**1984.5519
  **comparisonValueG:**2159.2307
  **comparisonValueR:**3420.9038

I do not understand what these values means. Can someone let me know what these values means and how I can find out if the images are similar or not.
Also doesn't the values suppose to be coming between 0 and 1 where 1 is the highest match and zero is the lowest?

I'm very new to OpenCV so please help me with this. If i'm comparing wrong please let me know of a correct method too.

Answer (score 0):

First your question is what does the number means. You first find the histogram. then normalize it. Then you compare the difference of two normalized histograms. See the image below. without normalize, it means the total number of a pixel at an intensity level. With normalization, it is the probability of finding a particular pixel at one color level. 
So what you are doing is compare the total difference of two PDF.

[image]

Second If your task is to compare and check if two images match each other. then compare histogram might be the worst option See example below. Your idea is 2 image is the same if their histogram is the same between A and B.  But I can show you that it is now the same as seen from the bottm.  In the bottom side, 2 histogram are the same, but image is represent different thing.

[image]

The simplist way to check if two image is the same is to do template matching. You can find the same code in the link below

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html

```
> void matchTemplate(InputArray image, InputArray templ, OutputArray
> result, int method)
```

[image]
[image]